# How to add PHP Validation

Tags: php, html

Im a super noob, how do you add validation so that your cant register a same username as another person?

```
$mysql_where    = "hidden";
$mysql_username = "hidden";
$mysql_password = "hidden";
$mysql_database = "hidden";
mysql_connect($mysql_where, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$status= 1;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`, `password`, `email`,`status`) 
VALUES('','$username','$password','$email','$status')");
mysql_close();
?>
Thank You For Registering, Please <a href=login.php>Login Here</a>
```

Comment: Make the username field unique and do a select before your insert to see if it's been taken.

Comment: Do a query to check if the username exists. 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'

Comment: http://www.php.net/function.mysql-num-rows or better yet http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows which is one method out of many. And don't use `md5` and `mysql_ugh*` - Both are old and do not fit today's standards for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you check that the username isn't in use by another person is the same as in real life - you rifle through the records to see if it's there already.

So the second part of j08691's comment works. Note that making the username field unique as suggested would enforce this rule independently of your code by not allowing two identical names to be in the table, but that might not be desirable if you want to keep expelled users in the same table as active users. (I note you have a status field).

There's also some amount of string manipulation that you'll want to do with the username - at present you're not even trimming it to remove any blanks from the end! That means you could have separate "Fred" and "Fred " users, which would be confusing.

Personally, I like a separate field for username_unique. I copy the requested username and process it heavily - remove all spaces, make it lowercase and replace accented characters etc. Much the same as you might a slug or subdomain. Indeed, if you ever intend to allow users to have a subdomain you'll want this level of uniqueness.

So before I save a user, I do a `SELECT` query on username_unique to see if there are more than 0 existing results. Potentially, you could combine this with the status so that usernames of expelled users could become available again. If there is already a match, I go back to the user and tell them. (That's pretty much the same as any form validation so I won't detail it here).

What you could do, to be extra nice, is to consider the possibility that a person attempting to register with an existing username might actually already have a user account they'd forgotten about. You could thus compare the email address - if it matches say 'Looks like you've already registered! Log in / forgot password' etc.